# ArangoDB: Traversals where edges are connected to other edges

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, aql

I recently read that ArangoDB is capable of connecting edges to other edges in a graph. In this situation, how would querying the path work? For example:

```
car <-------- part
        ^
        |
        |
installationEvidence
```

In this case, `installationEvidence` is a node connecting to the edge between the part to the car. Starting from the car node, what is the AQL to return `installationEvidence` but not `part`? Are both `installationEvidence` and `part` considered at the `p.vertices[1]` layer?

Answer (score 3):

In ArangoDB edges are a special type of Documents.
That is why you can store edges pointing to other edges.
From a query point of view there are two directions for this edges:
A) The traversal leads to the `target edge`. In this case it is assumed to be the general type of document and the traversal will not follow any direction of the `target edge`.
Which means you would have to write 2 traversals steps in the statement.
The first ending in the edge.
The second starting at `_from` or `_to` of the edge.
In your case the query could look like this:

```
FOR edge IN 1 OUTBOUND @installationEvidece @@edges1
  LET car = DOCUMENT(edge._to)
  RETURN car
```

B) A traversal walks through an edge which has  other edges pointing to it.
This case is more complicated. In ArangoDB's architecture the "vertex" does not know anything about it's attached edges, the edges know their vertices.
What you could do in this case is to again write two traversal statements where the second starts with the edge encountered, e.g.:

```
FOR part,edge IN 1 INBOUND @car @@edges1
  FOR installationEvidence IN 1 INBOUND edge @@edges2
    [...]
```

For the time being we did not encounter any use-case of customers to make the above traversal more transparent. If this is critical for you please contact us and we can increase the priority to make these kind of queries easier to formulate.

Comment: Good to know, I had no idea an edge can point to another edge, but it makes sense. Since an edge collection is just `_to` and `_from` then they can point at any valid `_id`.

Comment: Thanks for the great info! Does this mean that `for v, e, p in 1..2` with the `p.edges[1]` and `p.vertices[1]` syntax simply does not apply? This is a potential use-case for my team, however it's unlikely we will incorporate it in the near future. We're investigating it as a way to simplify our query structure and access some relevant data a little more directly.

Comment: We have not decided yet which syntax we want to use, if we can reuse the one that is already there (which i prefer) or if that would be extremely confusing. The thing here is if we go from `car` to `installationEvidence` how should `p` look like? `{vertices: [car, installationEvidence], edges: [car<--part, *<--evidence ]}` in this case it is pretty hard to identify the actual relation between vertices and edges. We are happy to help you with this and find a solution that fits both our needs.

Comment: Thank you! We've worked around this for now so that this isn't a critical need, but when we move to a database optimization phase we may come back to this!

Comment: @mchacki is there any news about this feature ?    
did ArangoDB team managed to define a unified syntax ?